# Does Spring IO Platform BOM support Java 1.6?

Tags: spring-io

I saw from the Spring IO Platform website (http://spring.io/blog/2014/06/26/introducing-the-spring-io-platform) and it states that Spring IO is certified to work with Java 1.7 and 1.8.

However, the production stack of my company is Java 1.6 only so may I know that does Spring IO Platform BOM support Java 1.6 as well?

We intensive use Spring, Spring Data, Spring Batch, Spring Integration, Spring Retry.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, Java 6 isn't supported by Spring IO Platform. That said, I'm not aware of anything in the projects that you have listed that require Java 7 so it may well work but it isn't something that we (Pivotal) have tested or support.